# How to fix Wordpress admin bar destroying 100% height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout, viewport

I'm creating a web site that fits to the screen with Wordpress.

When the site owner logs in, the admin bar will appear but it adds the following style:

```
html{ margin-top: 28px !important; }
```

This causes a vertical scroll bar to appear. Is there any way to fix this using just CSS?

[Someone had a similar issue](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/sticky-footer-being-destroyed-by-wordpress-admin-bar/) but he got no answer.

My relevant html structure:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <div id="page">
       <div class="site-main" id="main"> 
               <div class="content-area" id="primary">

                   <div role="main" class="site-content" id="content">

                   </div><!-- #content .site-content -->

               </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->         
           </div><!-- #main .site-main -->
       </div><!-- #page -->

       <div id="wpadminbar">

       </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

And relevant CSS:

```
html, body, #page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 350px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main {
    height: 100%;
}
#primary {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

For the admin bar:

```
#wpadminbar {
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

I've tried using (negative) margins and paddings, also setting the admin bar's `position` to `absolute` instead of `fixed` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php` at the beginning, and you will find this. Watch closely the comments for the actual answer:

```
if ( current_theme_supports( 'admin-bar' ) ) {
  /**
   * To remove the default padding styles
   * from WordPress for the Toolbar,
   * use the following code:
   * add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => '__return_false' ) );
   */
  $admin_bar_args = get_theme_support( 'admin-bar' );
  $header_callback = $admin_bar_args[0]['callback'];
}

if ( empty($header_callback) )
  $header_callback = '_admin_bar_bump_cb';

add_action('wp_head', $header_callback);
```

`wordpress/wp-includes/admin-bar.php` contains the default implementation of `_admin_bar_bump_cb`:

```
/**
 * Default admin bar callback.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 */
function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
  * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I can already do something with this, but when I remove the 28px margin of the HTML element the top 28px of the site just disappear under the admin bar. What can I do? Surely it must be possible to have a fixed 28px at the top and the actual site taking up the rest of the height?

Comment: Maybe you could fiddle with `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding-top` and `height: 100%`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: None of these methods really work, but I could use `overflow:hidden;` on the `html` tag and `overflow:auto` on the `body` tag.

Answer (score 6):

**2022** here.

I recently noticed that *WordPress* has been setting a relevant CSS variable on the front-end when logged in as an admin:

```css
html {
  --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 32px;
  scroll-padding-top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 782px)
  html {
    --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 46px;
  }
}
```

This is very convenient, as it allows you to do things like this (making a hero element as high as the viewport, but subtracting the height of the admin bar):

```css
.hero {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height));
}
```

There is a slight issue with that, though: If you’re *not* signed in as an admin, the CSS variable is not set, and this can break things like calculations.

This can be fixed by checking for a body class that *WordPress* also sets:

```css
.hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body.admin-bar .hero {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height));
}
```

…but this can get messy rather quickly, so I came up with a little one-size-fits-all solution that I’ll probably be using a lot:

```css
body:not(.admin-bar) {
  --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 0px;
}
```

This allows me to do things like this, and not having to worry about whether the user is logged in or not:

```css
.site-header {
  top: var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height);
}
```

Comment: It's probably the right solution if you have the fixed header and need to remove the admin bar height because the admin or other users is logged in, admin abar is not probably there but there is a blank space just before fixed header. 

`body:not(.admin-bar) {
  --wp-admin--admin-bar--height: 0px;
}`

Comment: How is that different from what I said?

Answer (score 1):

In your php code (on the page where you DON'T want the admin bar to appear), just add the following:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

See here: http://davidwalsh.name/hide-admin-bar-wordpress

Comment: It isn't on a specific page and I want the admin bar to be available at all times, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

````php
add_action('get_header', 'fix_adminbar');

function fix_adminbar()
{
    if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
        remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
        add_action(
            'wp_head', function () {
            ob_start();
            _admin_bar_bump_cb();
            $code = ob_get_clean();
            $code = str_replace('margin', 'padding', $code);
            $code = preg_replace('/{/', '{ box-sizing: border-box;', $code, 1);
            echo $code;
        }
        );
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution. It's working properly on my WP theme.

```css
#home-slider {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px; /* You can adjust the minimum height */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* If you want to vertically center the content */
    justify-content: center; /* If you want to horizontally center the content */
}

/* For desktop devices */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body.logged-in #home-slider {
        height: calc(100vh - 32px);
    }
}

/* For devices with a width up to 600px */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body.logged-in #home-slider {
        height: calc(100vh - 46px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**2024** here.

Just pass a fallback value to the CSS `var()` function:

```
min-height: calc(100svh - var(--wp-admin--admin-bar--height, 0px));
```

If `--wp-admin--admin-bar--height` is not defined (which happens when you are not logged in) it will fallback to `0px`.

PS.:

1. Better to use the `svh` css unit as it will also include the browser UI when calculating the viewport
2. In the answer above: `body:not(.admin-bar)` class selector did not work for me as it doesn't exist.